# Cannot create a connection to Dynamic Database data source

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2017, urlaccess

While trying to export a report as a PDF using URL Access, I ran in to a problem.
I'm trying to use a dynamic database/datasource for the data for this report.

I've set up a dynamic datasource according to the SSRS documentation, but this does not work. 
Using `Report/&DatabaseName=<Database I want to use>&ServerName=<Server>&rs:Format=PDF` as the parameters in the URL in Postman or Chrome, I always get this error: `Cannot create a connection to data source 'Dynamic_DB'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)`.

Is there a way that I can see more information about the error to see exactly what is going wrong or is there a direct way to fix this issue?
I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Kind Regards,
Devinloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the log files at \Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles and not getting any useful information from them, I cleared the project and re-made it. Following the exact steps I did before it worked now. A classic case of "turning it off and on again".